# Service to compile SASS online: is it safe to allow users manually import Compass extensions?

Tags: ruby, security, sinatra, sass, compass-sass

I'm creating another HTML/CSS fiddle web app. It is based on Sinatra and supports SASS with Compass extensions.

Here's how it works.

1) Require Compass and extensions:

```rb
require 'compass'
require 'singularitygs'
require 'breakpoint-slicer'
```

2) Add Compass load paths into Sass class:

```rb
Compass.sass_engine_options[:load_paths].each do |path|
  Sass.load_paths << path
end
```

This code is borrowed from [SassMeister](https://github.com/jedfoster/SassMeister/blob/master/sassmeister.rb#L92).

3) Receive an AJAX request with SASS, compile and return CSS:

```rb
post '/compile-sass' do
  sass = params[:sass]

  begin
    sass(sass.chomp, {:style => :nested, :quiet => true})
  rescue Sass::SyntaxError => e
    status 200
    e.to_s
  end if sass
end
```

Kinda very simple functionality. A user has to provide SASS code where manually he `@import`s any of supported Compass extensions:

```rb
@import breakpoint-slicer

html
  +from(3)
    background-color: pink
```

**Questions**:

1. Is it safe to let users import anything? When an extension outside of SASS load paths is being imported, SASS won't compile and throws an error. But JedFoster, the author of SassMeister, [considers](https://github.com/jedfoster/SassMeister/issues/2#issuecomment-16800506) such behavior a performance and security hole and has made SassMeister comment out manual imports. Why?
2. Is there anything that i can improve in the given code?

Comment: I don't know about the other questions, you might [ask Jed Foster directly](http://jedfoster.com/contact), but I'd change that status to [400](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) as that's what it's for, and `halt 400, e.to_s` is shorter.

Comment: @iain, this is not an option. With `status 200` the error text is retrieved by AJAX and pasted into the page for user to consider. The error text is a message from SASS compiler pointing at the problematic line. With `halt 400`, AJAX fails and reports a generic error.

Comment: What flavour of javascript are you using? For example, jQuery [allows you to pass in an error handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [define global error handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11705688/335847). I'm sure any of the other major js libraries support something similar.